# Recursion delete [Express & Mongoose]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have tree stucture like this:

```
[{
...,
childCode: [
    ...,
    childCode: []
]
},
{...,
childCode:[
]
}
]
```

And I want to delete all child codes...

I am able to do it wit recusion:

In my my code:

```
removeChild(code.childCode);

return res.json({
 message: "Code deleted!"
});
```

recusion function:

```
function removeChild(code) {
    if (code.length == 0) {
        console.log("done");
    } else
    {
        code.forEach(function (code) {
            setTimeout(function () {

                code.remove();

                removeChild(code.childCode);
            }, 100);


        });
    }
}
```

Is this right way to do this?

Comment: What is your tree schema? Is it `child reference`, `parent reference`, or `materialized path`?

Comment: Check out json strucutre... Each child can have one parent

Comment: The JSON structure does not actually reflect the scheme. For example, if you use `materialized path`, you can create and return that JSON structure in one simple query. Therefore, you only need 1 `Model.remove()` query.

Comment: Could you share example?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a tree like this:

```
__A
 |_B
 | |_C
 |
 |_D
```

---

This is how you save it in the database according to the `materialized path` pattern:

```
[
  { _id: 'A', path: 'A' },
  { _id: 'B', path: 'A/B' },
  { _id: 'C', path: 'A/B/C' },
  { _id: 'D', path: 'A/D' }
]
```

---

You can query the whole tree like this:

```
Node
  .find({ path: { $regex: /A/ } })
  .exec()
  .then(...);
```

Note: after querying, you can convert it to your JSON structure like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781983/build-a-json-tree-from-materialized-paths)

---

and remove whole tree like this:

```
Node
  .remove({ path: { $regex: /A/ } })
  .exec()
  .then(...);
```